# Taking samples of data using Latin Hypercube Sampling

Tags: sampling, latin-hypercube

Info: Newbie in Latin Hypercube Sampling (LHS)

I have a number of variables/parameters that have different number of elements:

$A = [1,2,3],$ $B = [1,2],$ and $C = [1,2,3,4]$

From these arrays I am creating a dataset (Cartesian product):

$$D = A \times B \times C$$

For the created dataset I have to run simulations in order to get the outputs/results, let's say:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} \\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{Row 2} & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ \hline
\text{Row 24} & 3 & 2 & 4\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Since the dataset could be very big and simulations are time-consuming, I want to use LHS to get samples from Dataset. How can I do it when I have different sizes of elements in different arrays, is it doable?

Also, in a case when I'd have the same size arrays, let's say:

$A = [1,2,3],$ $B = [1,2,3]$

I would have square dataset after Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{3} &  &  & \\ \hline
\text{2} &  &  & \\ \hline
\text{1} &  &  & \\ \hline
 & \text{1} & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{array}$ After LHS (random): $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{3} & * &  &  \\ \hline
\text{2} &  &  & * \\ \hline
\text{1} &  & * &  \\ \hline
& \text{1} & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{array}$ or $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{3} &  &  & * \\ \hline
\text{2} &  & * &  \\ \hline
\text{1} & * &  &  \\ \hline
& \text{1} & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

So, in this case, from the dataset generated I have to take:

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{A} & \text{B} \\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & 1 & 3 \\ \hline
\text{Row 2} & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{Row 3} & 3 & 2\\ \hline
\end{array}$ or $\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{A} & \text{B}\\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{Row 2} & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{Row 3} & 3 & 3\\ \hline
\end{array}$

Is this the right way of using LHS? And how could I use it in the case when I have different sizes of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This R code should do what you were asking for...

```
require(lhs)

A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c(1,2)
C <- c(1,2,3,4)

D <- expand.grid(A,B,C)

print(D)

# out of the 24 possible combinations, say that you wanted to find 10
#   combinations of the 3 variables

set.seed(1976)
X <- randomLHS(n = 10, k = 3)
pairs(X, labels = c("A","B","C"))

# now transforming the samples to your integers...
Y <- X
Y[,1] <- 1 + floor(X[,1] * length(A))
Y[,2] <- 1 + floor(X[,2] * length(B))
Y[,3] <- 1 + floor(X[,3] * length(C))

# or using a loop

Y <- X
lens <- c(length(A), length(B), length(C))
for (i in 1:3)
{
  Y[,i] <- 1 + floor(Y[,i] * lens[i])
}

pairs(Y, labels = c("A","B","C"), xlim = c(0,5), ylim = c(0,5), pch=19)

print(Y)

# check that there are no duplicates
nrow(Y) == nrow(unique(as.data.frame(Y)))
```

Comment: I see. I have just another question. What if I have an array A <- c(-4,-3,-2)? How could I fix it at the floor code?

Comment: You would use the Latin hypercube sample to index the A vector.  Like this...  Y[,1] <- A[1 + floor(X[,1] * length(A))]